# SELECT using UNION Clause

Tags: sql, oracle

For example . i having these 2 table

```
//DEPARTMENT
DNAME          CITY
--------------------
RESEARCH       BOSTON
   IT          CITY
 SCIENCE       DALLAS
RESEARCH       DALLAS
```

So i using this statement

```
(SELECT DNAME FROM DEPARTMENT WHERE CITY='BOSTON')
UNION
(SELECT DNAME FROM DEPARTMENT WHERE CITY='DALLAS'):
```

Using this statement i get this output

```
DNAME
-----
RESEARCH
SCIENCE
```

But my question is to choose either in 'BOSTON' or 'DALLAS' But not in both, my output should be like this

```
DNAME
--------
SCIENCE
```

What should i change in order to get the correct output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `INTERSECT` and `MINUS` (for Oracle):

```
-- At least at Boston or at Dallas 
(SELECT DNAME 
   FROM DEPARTMENT 
  WHERE CITY = 'DALLAS'

UNION

 SELECT DNAME 
   FROM DEPARTMENT 
  WHERE CITY = 'BOSTON')

MINUS

-- At Boston and at Dallas
(SELECT DNAME 
   FROM DEPARTMENT 
  WHERE CITY = 'DALLAS'

INTERSECT

 SELECT DNAME 
   FROM DEPARTMENT 
  WHERE CITY = 'BOSTON')
```

Since `UNION` *adds* subqueries up while `EXCEPT`/`MINUS` *subtracts* them

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out the dnames first and then use group by to select only those dnames that are present in one city only.

```
select dname
  from department
 where city in ('BOSTON', 'DALLAS')
 group by dname
having count(city) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: UNION automatically removes all the duplicates. Since, DNAME is the only returned column, it will remove duplicates

**Edit**
For distinct selection of either DNAME in 'DALLAS' or 'BOSTON', something like this:

```
    SELECT DNAME FROM DEPARTMENT 
                 WHERE (CITY='BOSTON' and CITY<>'DALLAS')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use ROWNUM psudocolumn ,  see the Fidde  [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7848e/3/0)